# What can I change the default font in themeroller to?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, webfonts, themeroller

I'm working with jQuery Mobile and I'm building my theme using ThemeRoller. I see that the default is set to be `Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif` but instead of giving other options it allows me to write in my own. Is there a way to implement any font that I like or am I only restricted to web safe fonts? I assume that it would allow anything being CSS3 based but once again, I am stumped on how to implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your own font names, but if they're not web-safe fonts you'll have to include [`@font-face` rules](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) separately.

Comment: so once I download that finished theme when I'm done with it, I can go into the CSS it makes and add the @font-face as I would on a normal website?

Comment: Yep, or include it in a separate CSS file.